# Disable Time Machine on a Mac - tmutil disable doesn't work

Tags: macos, time-machine

I want to permanently disable Time Machine on a mac. I can grey out the System Preferences Time Machine Tab, but I can't prevent the user from reenabling it on the terminal.
So I wanted to write a script that disables Time Machine every time the mac is rebooted.
But I can't get the command line

```
sudo tmutil disable
```

to work. Even when Time Machine is running a backup the command line won't do anything. It just goes on.

Can you explain this to me?

Comment: Why don't you just set no backup locations?

Comment: I just realised - you mean another admin user? Either make them not an admin, or remove their sudo rights, otherwise they can undo anything you do.

Comment: The mac will be used by developers in our company. They should be able to work as freely as possible, so we'd like them to have sudo rights... But Time Machine violates our company's compliance rules, so we want to disable just Time Machine completely. Using VMwares Airwatch for Management. There you can turn Time Machine off and it's not visible anymore in the system preferences. But we want to prevent the user from turning it on again via the termianl.

Comment: You might need to look at some type of MDM solution, but that's beyond my experience, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the `sudo tmutil stopbackup` command to abort a current running backup process. "disable" just prevents automatic backups.

To prevent getting the offer to backup with TM to new inserted drives execute the settings command

`defaults write com.apple.TimeMachine DoNotOfferNewDisksForBackup -bool true`

I haven't tested this with all modern versions of macOS, but worth a try.

Answer (score -2):

In the end "Santa" did the job :)

Santa is actually an application, which can be used to block other applications.

You can get Santa here:
https://github.com/google/santa

Santa is a black/whitelisting application. You set up a server where you indicate the applications that the clients are allowed or not allowed to use and then install the santa app on the client.

Every time the user wants to start an application that is blacklisted, Santa blocks it and leaves a customizable messege. You can also block applications like TimeMachine, that you can control via the terminal. So, we blocked "tmutil" and now TimeMachine can't be reactivated on the clients.